# Guide for ROS2/colcon project in CLion

Tags: ros, ros2, ide, clion

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a guide for using CLion IDE to build/debug ROS2 with colcon on a mixed python/CPP project? CLion was awesome for this with ROS1 projects, for source level debugging with variable watch/modify and using IntelliJ for project navigation and refactoring. I want to get away from any ROS1/catkin/ament stuff and I do not understand the colcon/CMake/make toolchain or the CLion configuration enough to tackle it.

An example using the standard ROS tutorials/example projects would be terrific since I already know that I can build those using colcon build.

One plausible workaround would be to have colcon build generate a top level CMakeLists.txt file? If that is indeed possible then CLion may be able to open the project that way (that worked for ROS1)

Eventually I would like to be able to use Docker environments to assist with collaborative development but I am not interested in that extra layer just yet.

ENV Info:
Ubuntu 18.04.3 x64 Kernel 5.3.0-40-generic
CLion 19.3.4
ROS2 Eloquent

I also have a similar support request open at JetBrains:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-19558

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/347559/guide-for-ros2/colcon-project-in-clion/) by [Ciel](https://answers.ros.org/users/52835/ciel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2020-03-25

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2020-03-26**:
`catkin_make_isolated` / `catkin_tools` / `colcon` / ROS 2 conceptionally all don't support a workspace-level CMake file since that approach doesn't work on a larger scale (see http://design.ros2.org/articles/ament.html#building-within-a-single-cmake-context).

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2020-03-26**:
I have never used CLion before. Maybe this (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/compilation-database.html) approach can be helpful. There is a PR to `colcon-cmake` to generate a workspace-level compilation database, see https://github.com/colcon/colcon-cmake/pull/69.

**Comment by [*andrei*](https://answers.ros.org/users/57604/_andrei_/) on 2021-01-26**:
Thank you both for the links. I tried to use Compilation Database in CLion, but it can be used now only to check compilation errors. It can't build and can't show cmake issues.

Also I tried previous approach with single cmake, indeed, it is not supported at all. I gave up when trying to depend on custom messages from the same workspace.

People suggest to use VCode for ROS2, but it's the last thing I want to try...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

CLion IDE can be conveniently used with ros2. It happens thanks to CLion support of Compilation Database (CD) and colcon creating a top-level CD file for the entire workspace. Here is how to set it up:

1. Build your ros2 project workspace with [CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS.html), e.g. `colcon build --cmake-args -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=1`.
2. This creates a `compile_commands.json` file in your `build/` directory. You need to copy it to top-level directory of your workspace (where you have `src/` and `build/` directories. You can automate this step.
3. Run your CLion, click `File->Open`, and select the `compile_commands.json` file, open it as a project.
4. Things should work now. To check, hold Ctrl over an object of a class from another workspace package or from your ros2 distro package. You should be able to navigate to definitions with Ctrl-click.

---

Originally posted by [Adam Dabrowski](https://answers.ros.org/users/70080/adam-dabrowski/) with karma: 116 on 2021-08-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 10

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Minphie](https://answers.ros.org/users/25528/minphie/) on 2021-11-30**:
Then answer is very helpful but then  how can I debug a ros2 node in clion?

**Comment by [magladko](https://answers.ros.org/users/134470/magladko/) on 2023-01-17**:
For the new visitors, there is a tutorial by JetBrains: [ROS2 with Clion tutorial](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/ros2-tutorial.html)
I prepared some basic Github repo for Ubuntu users, so You can take a look (it's very basic): [repo](https://github.com/magladko/ros2-clion-automation)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a CMakeLists.txt file here that you can use to import into CLion: https://gist.github.com/rotu/1eac858b808b82bbf1b475f515e91636

Place this CMakeLists.txt file in your ros2_ws root.

To import all the projects in your workspace, comment out the --packages-select line at the end.

For large workspaces such as a full ROS 2 build, it is recommended to just select a few to build with the --packages-select option.

Steps to import are:

1. colcon build
2. source install/setup.bash
3. Launch clion from that terminal
4. Open the CMakeLists.txt in the workspace root

---

Originally posted by [calvertdw](https://answers.ros.org/users/29941/calvertdw/) with karma: 25 on 2020-10-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1